# Tkinter window not displaying widgets

Tags: python, class, tkinter, toplevel

1. This code does not show any widgets in the main window. Any solutions?
2. Is there a way to create multiple toplevel windows in one single module? Currently, I am creating new python module for each toplevel window.
3. Also, after creating a new top level window, do we use mainloop or update or update_ideltasks?

Thank you!

```
    class MainWindowWidgets(ttk.Frame):
        def __int__(self, container):
           super().__init__(container)
    
           create_frame = ttk.LabelFrame(container, text='New Frame')
           create_frame.grid(row=0, column=0)
    
           create_btn = ttk.Button(create_frame, text='New Button')
           create_btn.grid(row=0, column=0)
    
    
    class App(tk.Tk):
        def __init__(self):
            super().__init__()
            self.title('My App')
            self.geometry('1000x500')
            self.resizable(False, False)
            main_window_widgets = MainWindowWidgets(self)
            main_window_widgets.pack()
    
    
    # This function is called from login window if login is successful and login window is destroyed

    def open_main_window():
        app = App()
        app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues in your `MainWindowWidgets` class:

- `__int__(...)` should be `__init__(...)` instead
- `self` should be used instead of `container` as the parent of `create_frame`

```py
class MainWindowWidgets(ttk.Frame):
    # __int__ should be __init__ instead
    #def __int__(self, container):
    def __init__(self, container):
       super().__init__(container)

       # use self instead of container as the parent
       #create_frame = ttk.LabelFrame(container, text='New Frame')
       create_frame = ttk.LabelFrame(self, text='New Frame')
       create_frame.grid(row=0, column=0)

       create_btn = ttk.Button(create_frame, text='New Button')
       create_btn.grid(row=0, column=0)
```

Comment: Thank you @awc1668. Well, I hit tab never realized it auto filled __int__ the entire time.